Почему функция print() ничего не выводит в цикле?
cache = {}

def f(n):
    if n not in cache:
        if n > 100000: cache[n] =  n
        else: cache[n] = f(n + 1) + 5 * n + 2
    return cache[n]

for i in range(100001, 99990):
    print(f(i))


Потому что 99990 < 100001. Из-за этого range(100001, 99990) не содержит элементов, и ничего не выполняется

действительно, я невнимательный)
